# Laravel Mix import JS return errors

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, npm, laravel-mix

Laravel 5.4, NPM 5.8.0

After compile the assets I'm getting this error on every js library that is loaded on before bootstrap.js...

[image: This is the app.js on resources folder]

[image: After perform a npm run dev got this error on console]

[image: Then moved everything above of bootstrap lib]

[image: And now is not modernizr error, is jQuery scrollbar]

What type of thing I'm missing? I have no modified any core of laravel, Just add the JS libs and compile with npm run dev.

Answer (score 0):

Just missed that app.js load bootstrap and jquery by default, So first, removed the duplicate require that load jQuery

```
//require('./jobhunt/jquery.min');
```

Next, Modernizr is loaded on my base layout (welcome.blade.php) on the head.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/js/jobhunt/modernizr.js') }}"></script>
```

Last, I've detected that my template has deprecated or older versions of jQuery.scrollbar, waypoints, and jQuery counterUp, So I upgraded and now this is the result:

[image]

[image]

So, I think that is because the theme has old libs and I think that is important leave the bootstrap on top of any require lib. Now my console is clean of errors.